Ceiling Fan use of Lock Nuts
Is it recommended that a lock nut be used with the screws used to mount a ceiling fan to the electrical box?

If the instructions for a UL/ETL-listed* ceiling fan do not mention using a lock nut, then you don't need to use one.
Note that you may need to upgrade the existing electrical box to a ceiling-fan-compatible box. Look carefully at the box to see if it has anything stamped in it about ceiling fans.
(* or whatever safety certification exists in your location on the planet.)
